# How does the `type` callable show two overloaded signatures in PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

The `type` callable in Python can be used in two ways; with one argument it returns the class of the argument, and with three arguments it returns a new class.

In PyCharm, code completion for the `type` callable makes it appear that `type` is overloaded, by presenting both the first and second option for invoking `type`:

[image]

**How is PyCharm able to display the two ways of invoking `type` as seen in the picture above ?**

Is this something we can also accomplish with our own user defined callables, or is this a special case that PyCharm hardcodes for `type`?

---

In PyCharm if I double click on `type` I get sent to the `__init__` defintion of `type` in  `builtins.py`. However this shows something different:

[image]

This shows that Pycharm isn't inspecting the doc string or anything fancy.

In addition, this definition doesn't include any type hints, yet the pycharm code completion shows type hints for both ways of calling `type`. How does it know to do this?

Comment: Maybe official docs of [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) could be a source?

Comment: @OlvinRoght it looks close, but it is still off. For example the official docs say `type(object)` and `type(name, bases, dict, **kwds)` whereas Pycharm says `o: object`; and `name: str, bases: tuple[type, ...], dict: dict[str, Any], **kwds)`. Moreover, how would Pycharm pull this from the docs?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen Pycharm pulls annotations for the std lib from Typeshed https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html#typeshed. As for how to provide annotations for multiple ways of invoking a function see https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks, I found the implementation of the `type` stub used by Typeshed [here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L165). Please feel free to post an answer with this direct link and a brief explanation and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen Added a brief answer, feel free to add to it if it's lacking

Comment: Related: [How to define overloaded type signatures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68552210/12299000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm uses the [Typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed) package to get the annotations and definitions for the Python standard library as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html#typeshed). This package contains stub files (`.pyi` files) that provide the annotations. Specifically, the `type` stub can be found [here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L165):

```
@overload
def __init__(self, __o: object) -> None: ...
@overload
def __init__(self, __name: str, __bases: tuple[type, ...], __dict: dict[str, Any], **kwds: Any) -> None: ...
```

To annotate a function with multiple different signatures you can use the [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) decorator to provide multiple annotations for the same function, example below. [This is how Typeshed provides two different definitions for the type function](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L165)

```
@overload
def foo(bar: int) -> int:
    ...

@overload
def foo(bar: str) -> str:
    ...

def foo(bar):
    # func body
```